# Unable to take user input command in pssh command

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the OS command from user input and export and use in function, like below

```
export command5=date
export command4=uname
```

Its working in below command

```
pssh -h /tmp/cus6 -i "$command5;$command4"
[1] 04:17:06 [SUCCESS] Server1
Mon Jan 28 03:17:06 UTC 2019
Linux
[2] 04:17:06 [SUCCESS] Server2
Mon Jan 28 03:17:06 UTC 2019
Linux
```

But didn't work when trying to keep commands in one line

```
pssh -h /tmp/cus6 -i 'echo $(echo ), $(command5), $(command4)'
[1] 04:26:45 [SUCCESS] Server1
, ,
Stderr: bash: command5: command not found
bash: command4: command not found
[2] 04:26:45 [SUCCESS] Server2
, ,
Stderr: bash: command5: command not found
bash: command4: command not found
```

But same is working in keeping commands instead of command5 & command4

```
pssh -h /tmp/cus6 -i 'echo $(echo ), $(date), $(uname)'
[1] 04:30:01 [SUCCESS] Server1
, Mon Jan 28 03:30:01 UTC 2019, Linux
[2] 04:30:01 [SUCCESS] Server2
, Mon Jan 28 03:30:01 UTC 2019, Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the *local* variable to be expanded, you will need to replace the outer single quotes with double quotes.

Then, in order to pass the command substitution to the *remote* shell, you will need to quote (or escape) that.

Ex.

```
$ cmd='uname -r'

$ parallel-ssh -h hostsfile -i "echo \$($cmd)"
[1] 22:38:52 [SUCCESS] vm
4.4.0-141-generic
[2] 22:38:52 [SUCCESS] localhost
4.15.0-43-generic
```

Related: [In some places awk doesn't work in pssh command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113260/in-some-places-awk-doesnt-work-in-pssh-command/1113287?noredirect=1#comment1837970_1113287)

Comment: awk again having an issue, when user inputs any command with awk -  
uname -a|awk "{print \$3}"   is not taking .

command1:, command, not found